# Can I search a vector of vectors of characters to find a specific character and get its coordinates?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a map of a room that I have put into a vector of vectors of characters (vector>). The map will look something like this:

```
# * #
* * D
S * #
```

where # are walls, * are path areas, S is the start and D is the end. I will not know what the map looks like ahead of time so I want my program to be able to read any map with similar characteristics to the one above.

Thus, I would like to be able to search my vector of vectors to find the coordinates/location of S, so I know where the starting point of the maze is. I have only been able to find examples for just a single vector (one-dimension). Is this possible to do with a vector of vectors (two-dimensions)? If so, how can I do it?

Here is the code I used to create the matrix:

```
vector<vector<char>> GetMap(int& M, int& N) //function to get the map of a room
{
    vector<vector<char>> matrix{}; //give a matrix
    char char_buf;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++)
    {
        matrix.push_back(vector<char>()); //Put a new empty row in your matrix
        for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++)
        {
            cin >> char_buf; //Here we get a char from cin
            matrix.back().push_back(char_buf); //That you push back in your sub-vector
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: You can write a function `std::vector<std::pair> getCoordinates(const std::vector<std::vector>& map, char toFind);` which searches through your matrix.

Comment: `S` and `D` exist only once. So you can compare the input after `cin` and if it is one of these two, you can store the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `GetMap` function is constantly pushing back new elements. That's a big no no when you already have the size of the matrix available to you (`M` and `N`). Also, there is really no need for the size parameters to be of type `int&`. A simple int is fine and, in most cases, even more efficient.

Rule of thumb: Only use references for non-basic types like `vector`, `string` and pretty much all classes.

Also, the fact that you use `int&` and not `const int&` doesn't allow you to call the function by passing rvalues (variables without names). For example `GetMap(5, 5)`.

Now, to finally answer your question. Since you already have an idea on how to parse the whole matrix in your `GetMap` function. I really don't see the problem in creating a similar function that would get the position of a desired character.

The full working code with some enhancements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Pos{
    Pos()             : x(0), y(0) {}
    Pos(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    int x;
    int y;
};

vector<vector<char>> GetMap(const int height, const int width) //function to get the map of a room
{
    //Create the matrix with the constructor (much more efficent than constantly push_back'ing elements)
    vector<vector<char>> matrix(height, vector<char>(width));

    //Go through every single char in the matrix
    for (int rows = 0; rows < height; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < width; cols++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

Pos getElementPos(const vector<vector<char>>& matrix, const char toFind)
{
    int height = matrix.size();
    int width  = matrix[0].size();

    //Go through every single char in the matrix
    for (int rows = 0; rows < height; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < width; cols++)
        {
           if(matrix[rows][cols] == toFind){
               return Pos(cols, rows);
           }
        }
    }

    // In the event that we couldn't find the element
    return Pos(-1, -1);
}

int main(){
    vector<vector<char>> map = GetMap(5, 5);

    Pos dPos = getElementPos(map, 'D');

    cout << "\nThe coordinates of D are " << dPos.x << " and " << dPos.y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```